# Why can't we use mathematical induction?

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

I'm studying Computability Complexity and Languages by Maritn D. Davis. In chapter 3, section 6, theorem 6.1, he says:

> Let $C$ be a PRC class. If $f(t,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ belongs to C, then so do the functions $$g(y,x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{t=0}^y f(t,x_1,\dots,x_n)$$ and $$h(y,x_1,\dots,x_n) = \prod_{t=0}^y f(t,x_1,\dots,x_n)$$

I don't understand why can't we use mathematical induction to prove this theorem. I appreciate your help.

I don't understand the downvotes either. I'm confused and just asked for a little explanation! :)

Comment: How exactly would you use induction?

Comment: @MarkSaving For y = 0, it is correct. If for y = k it's correct then for y = k+1 we have $g(k+1,...,x_n) = g(k,...,x_n) + f(k+1,...,x_n)$. So it's correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's correct"? Can you be more precise about what that means?

Comment: @MarkSaving $f(k+1,...,x_n)$ by definition belongs to the class $C$, by induction hypothesis we know that $g(k,...x_n)$ also belongs to the class $C$. It also can be proven that $h(x,y) = x + y$ is also belongs to $C$ by recursion and combination of initial functions. So $g(k+1,...,x_n)$ is the combination of the functions which belong to $C$. So it belongs to $C$, too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a naive "proof by induction". I will first go through the "proof" and then explain why it fails.

> I claim that for all $y$, the function $g(y, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is in $C$.
>
> To prove this, we proceed by induction on $y$. In the base case, $y = 0$. Then $g(0, x_1, \ldots, x_n) = f(0, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is clearly in $C$.
>
> For the inductive step, let $y = k + 1$ and suppose that $g(k, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is in $C$. Then $g(k + 1, x_1, \ldots, x_n) = g(k, x_1, \ldots, x_n) + f(k + 1, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is clearly in $C$. $\square$

The error here is rather subtle. The claim is that for all $y$, the function $g(y, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is in $C$. But the problem is that this is not a meaningful statement (or, to the extent it is meaningful, it is highly misleading). Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as "the function $g(y, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$". Instead, there is a function $g$ which is defined by the defining equation $\forall y \forall x_1 \ldots \forall x_n (g(y, x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum\limits_{t = 0}^y f(t, x_1, \ldots, x_n))$.

So formally speaking, the first line should be

> I claim that for all $y$, the function $g$ is primitive recursive, where $g$ is defined by the fact that for all $y, x_1, \ldots, x_n$, $g(y, x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum\limits_{t = 0}^y f(t, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.

The issue is now laid plain. We quantify over the variable $y$ twice - once in the clause "I claim that for all $y$", and once in the clause defining $g$ - "I claim that for all $y, x_1, \ldots, x_n$". This means that the $y$s in question do not refer to the same thing. In fact, the statement

> the function $g$ is primitive recursive, where $g$ is defined by the fact that for all $y, x_1, \ldots, x_n$, $g(y, x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \sum\limits_{t = 0}^y f(t, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.

Actually does not depend at all on the original $y$ mentioned in the clause "I claim that for all $y$".

From here, we can easily see that the steps we took in our induction - in particular, the base case - were not valid to prove what we set out to prove.

However, we still did prove something. The thing we actually proved is as follows:

> I claim that for all $y$, the function $w$ is primitive recursive, where $w$ is defined by the fact that for all $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, $w(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = g(y, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.

It is easy to see that the steps of our induction suffice to prove this statement. But this does not necessarily mean that $g$ is primitive recursive.

To illustrate this point, consider any function $k : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, and consider the function $g(y, x) = k(y)$. Then for all $y$, we see that the function $w$, defined by $w(x) = g(y, x)$, is a constant function of $x$ and therefore primitive recursive. But this does not necessarily mean that $g$ is primitive recursive. For if $g$ were primitive recursive, then $k$ would also have to be primitive recursive, since $k$ can be defined by the equation $k(x) = g(x, 0)$. So if we could conclude that $g$ is primitive recursive, then we could conclude that *any* function of one argument is primitive recursive. And this is not true.